# how to apply LDAP in Angular 2?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, ldap, mean-stack

I am stuck how to apply LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) in Angular 2 ?
Can anyone please help me out ?
I am not been able to find any perfect implimentation for Active Directory
I am working with MEAN stack Technology node.js as backend and mongodb as my nosql Database

Comment: AFAIK, you can't really provide LDAP authentication directly in the frontend without any backend managing it. A google search turned up the [Auth0 guide](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/ldap/), which uses Auth0's own SaaS so you might want to implement it differently using your own backend - but nonetheless authentication is the backend's job, not the frontend's.

Answer (score 0):

Please [click here](https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2017/08/04/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-in-an-angular-4-3-1-application-with-a-stand-alone-web-api) for detailed information on using LDAP for windows authentication in Angular. I hope it would be useful for you.

Comment: i am using node.js as backend and angular as frontend so how to do it ?

Comment: For MEAN stack, to implement security, see this link.  https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/

If you were intending to use LDAP for implementing security, my recommendation is to try the above alternate way to secure the application.